# How can I show that $(1,0)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show that $(1,0)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

To show that, I think I need to show $(1,0)$ can't be factored into a product of a finite number of irreducibles.

Maybe I can use a contradiction?
I know that $(1,0) = (1,0) (1,0)$ or $(-1,0)(-1,0)$ and neither $(1,0)$ nor $(-1,0)$ is irreducible but I'm not sure how to proceed from this.

Comment: What do you mean by "irreducible" in a ring that isn't an integral domain?

Comment: @ZevChonoles, it is a non-zero element which is not a unit and whose only divisors are the trivial ones. There is no requiremenet the ring is an integral domain AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

An irreducible element $r$ is a non-unit with the property that for any $a,b$ with $ab=r$, then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. $(1,0)$ is not a unit, and clearly does not have this property (by the factorizations you gave) , so it is not irreducible.

Usually we only care about irreducible elements over integral domains, because of this exact problem. Reducible elements "should" be the product of irreducible elements, but even in something as simple as $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ we get no irreducible elements.

Comment: +1 - I'm not sure whether this definition of irreducible is standard, but it seems reasonable and this answer gives good intuition of why things only *really* work in an integral domain.

Comment: Not only standard: I think most books use this definition (the only one I know, btw), but with one little addition: the element $\,r\,$ is usually required to bne non-zero.

Comment: Personally I want $0$ to be a part of my primes (in an integral domain) as $(0)$ is a prime ideal and $0$ satisfies the prime property.